# C# random.Next() flags .Next() as an error?

Tags: c#, random

I'm new to C# (but not to coding), so if this is an easy fix please forgive me. I'm attempting to get the computer to generate a random number between 1 and 100,000. However, when mimicking the syntax I saw online, I receive the error "CS1061: 'Random' does not contain a definition for 'Next'and no extension method 'Next' accepting a first argument of type 'Random' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

When attempting to add "using System.Random();", the computer tells me the using directive is unneccessary, but when one gets rid of using it just creates more problems.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NumberWizard : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    print("Welcome to Number Wizard!");
    print("Pick a number in your head, but don't tell me!");

    int max = 100000, min = 1;

    print("Choose a number between "+min+" and "+max+".");
    Random r = new Random();
    int guess1 = r.Next();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your `Random` is `UnityEngine.Random`, not `System.Random`. Fully qualify it, e.g. `System.Random r = new System.Random()`.

(There are other ways of doing this. If you do not need the `UnityEngine` namespace here, remove it and add `using System;`, then `Random` will be the one you want.)

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you.

```
public System.Random r = new System.Random();
public int guess1 = r.Next(0, 100000);
```

I suppose that this is your error, since from the error message you get, it's clear that the `UnityEngine.Random` class is used and not the System.Random.

**Update**

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

You have to make you `r` to be static

```
public static System.Random r = new System.Random();
public int guess1 = r.Next(0, 100000);
```

Comment: I followed what you said and the error is now in r- "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property "NumberWizard.r"

Comment: @AveryRyan: Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Should I keep that in the Start function or should I move that somewhere else?

Comment: You can make your start function to the constructor would be nice I think

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NumberWizard : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        print("Welcome to Number Wizard!");
        print("Pick a number in your head, but don't tell me!");

        int max = 100000, min = 1;

        print("Choose a number between " + min + " and " + max + ".");
        print( Random.Range(min,max));

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

I guess random's usage is a bit different in Unity.